# JQuery, MVC & Master Pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

What is the correct way to include the JQuery libraries via a master page?  It appears there is a set for development and a set for production.  I tried an "#if DEBUG" in my master page and it tripped errors left and right.  I was also using <% %> style code and found out that I am not allowed to do that either.  And my google-fu has not been good lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scott Gu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx) had a post on this a while back.

But essentially all you need on the master page is a link (as Alex posted earlier)

You can use code blocks to include a Intellisense version by doing :

```
<% if ( false ){ %>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-vsdoc.js"></script>
<% } %>
```

on any of the individual pages which you require intellisense on.

Comment: When doing anything with code nuggets in the site.master I get: {"The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."}.  While I did ask about JQuery I also have other JS files to include.  What I *wanted* to do was:
<% #if DEBUG { %>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/Debug/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% } else { %>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% } %>

Of course, none of this works in the site.master.

Comment: Actually - this works (per Phil Haack's blog entry http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/27/controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-issue-with-asp.net-mvc-rc1.aspx)<br/>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="mainScripts">
<% #if DEBUG %>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/Debug/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% #else %>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% #endif %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Will include jQuery off Google's servers. The production one is the minified version (smaller file size).

Including this one will benefit you- There is a good chance (with more developers adopting this technique) that the person will have already visited a site with this link, and therefore having jQuery cached).

Comment: You can't, unfortunately. Best you can do is vote them both up, and pick the one which helped you most as the accepted answer.